# Get Travis CI build state value

Tags: rest, curl, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Is there a way to get the Travis CI build status:

This is my uri:

> `GET https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/xxxx/yyy/builds`

and I get a 200 OK response with valid build details

```
[
  {
    "id": 111682543,
    "repository_id": 7354140,
    "number": "219",
    "result": 0,
    "state": "passed",
    "started_at": "2016-02-24T19:05:33Z",
    "finished_at": "2016-02-24T19:06:52Z",
  }
]
```

I need to fetch the 'id','state' value. Could someone tell me how I could get this value?

Comment: Use a JSON parser, the path is `result_obj[0].result`, FWIW

Comment: Thanks for the lead набиячлэвэлиь

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json" "https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/xxxx/yyyy/builds" > test.json

LATEST_STATE=$(grep -o '"state":.[a-z\"]*' test.json | head -1)

LATEST_ID=$(grep -o '"id":.[0-9]*' test.json | head -1 | grep ':.[0-9]*')
```

This would output:

```
"{state}": "passed"

"{id}": "111682543"
```